# Using hooks in a higher order component

Tags: reactjs

I would like to develop a new feature, which previously would have lived in a higher order component, using hooks. However, since according to the [React Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-hooks-classes-or-a-mix-of-both):

"You can’t use Hooks inside of a class component, but you can definitely mix classes and function components with Hooks in a single tree."

So let's say I have some existing class component `ExistingComponent` that I want to extend with additional functionality, say, listening to `window.resize`. I would expect to do it like this.

```
// Existing Component
export class ExistingComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>I exist!</div>;
  }
}

// Hook
export const useWindowResize = () => {
  function resize() {
    console.log('window resized!');
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
    return function cleanup() {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', resize);
    };
  });
};

// HOC
export const withWindowResize = component => {
  useWindowResize();
  return component;
};

// Extended Component
export const BetterComponent = withWindowResize(ExistingComponent);
```

However, this fails with `Uncaught Invariant Violation: Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.` I do use `react-hot-loader`, but I am still able to use hooks in component functions that don't return a class component. Also, I can remove the `useWindowResize()` from the function and it renders as expected.

I am also able to render the example provided in the docs, so I know it's not a problem with hooks generically:

```
function Example() {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Is this the wrong approach?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can return a new function component from your `withWindowResize` HOC in which you call the hook and spread the props on the component you pass in.

You can also pass an empty array as second argument to `useEffect` to only have it run once after the initial render.

```js
const { useEffect } = React;

class ExistingComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>I exist!</div>;
  }
}

const useWindowResize = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    function resize() {
      console.log('window resized!');
    }
    window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', resize);
    };
  }, []);
};

const withWindowResize = Component => {
  return (props) => {
    useWindowResize();
    return <Component {...props} />;
  }
};

const BetterComponent = withWindowResize(ExistingComponent);

ReactDOM.render(<BetterComponent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```